# Add Security Groups to Instance in Openstack

Tags: java, cloud, openstack, jclouds

I am trying to use Apache JClouds to add/remove a particular Security Group to some instances (which are already running) in a zone. I know that this can be done using the Nova-CLI. Could some one point out how this is done using jclouds? The documentation doesnt really say all that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NovaApi novaApi = ContextBuilder
        .newBuilder("openstack-nova")
        .credentials("username", "api_key")
        .buildApi(NovaApi.class);

Ingress ingress = Ingress.builder().fromPort(80).toPort(80).ipProtocol(IpProtocol.TCP).build();

SecurityGroupApi securityGroupApi = novaApi.getSecurityGroupExtensionForZone("RegionOne").get();
SecurityGroup securityGroup = securityGroupApi.createWithDescription("name", "description");
SecurityGroupRule rule = securityGroupApi.createRuleAllowingCidrBlock(securityGroup.getName(), ingress, "0.0.0.0/0");
securityGroupApi.delete(securityGroup.getId());
```